# Understanding Hibernate cascade behavior with multiple item references

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I don't understand a certain Hibernate behavior regarding an object that should be persisted by a Cascade.ALL setting, but is then regarded as unsaved in another reference in the same transaction.

Example:

```
OrderProposal proposal = new OrderProposal();
ProposalLineItem proposalLine = new ProposalLineItem();
proposalLine.setProposal(proposal);
proposal.addLineItem(proposalLine); //to be saved by cascade.all via proposal
saveOrUpdate(proposal);

Order order = new Order();
OrderLineItem orderLine = new OrderLineItem(); //to be saved by cascade.all via order
orderLine.setProposalLine(proposalLine); //proposalLine is not mapped as cascaded from orderLine
proposalLine.setOrderLine(orderLine);
order.addLineItem(orderLine);
saveOrUpdate(order);
```

If this is run in a single transaction, Hibernate throws when processing the cascades of the order object:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an 
unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : orderLine.proposalLine
```

Do I have to save proposalLine explicitly for getting this to work?

**EDITED**

Here are the affected hibernate mappings:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.VERSION)
public class ProposalLineItem {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "proposal_id")
    private OrderProposal proposal;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "proposalLine")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION)
    private OrderLineItem orderLine;
}


@Entity
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.VERSION)
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class OrderProposal {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proposal", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "listIndex", nullable = false)
    private List<ProposalLineItem> lineItems;

}



@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.VERSION)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class OrderLineItem {

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION)
    @JoinColumn(name = "proposal_line_id", nullable = false)
    private ProposalLineItem proposalLine;

}



@Entity
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.VERSION)
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Order {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    @IndexColumn(nullable = false, name = "listIndex", base = 0)
    private List<OrderLineItem> lineItems;

}
```

Comment: Could you show the relevant mappings?

Comment: Which object is throwing the exception ?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: This may be related to the id generation strategy. Could you show the id mappings for all the entities?

Comment: @Column(columnDefinition = "char(36)")
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUIDIdGenerator")
 @GenericGenerator(name = "UUIDIdGenerator", strategy = "our.legacy.UUIDIdGenerator"). This generates a 8-4-4-4-12 digit uuid.

Comment: Ok, is the order you call `saveOrUpdate` the same one as in your posted code (you first call `saveOrUpdate(proposal)`, then `saveOrUpdate(order)`)?

Comment: yes, I verified this already, since the order is supposed to be important according to the hibernate docs

Comment: Then, I'm out of options; I cannot reproduce your issue with the mappings you provided. Could you just extend the code you posted for `OrderProposal` with the implementation of `addLineItem`? I assume nothing spectacular is there, but lets look at it as well, just to exclude it as a possible cause of the issue.

Comment: I try to create an isolated case to reproduce the issue and post it here

Answer (score 0):

> Cascade is a convenient feature to save the lines of code needed to
>   manage the state of the other side manually.

Let us suppose one scenario,where one object depend on the other one and you want to delete it how you will delete it? You have to fire the 1 after other query manually if cascading not there. So in hibernate cascading attribute is mandatory where you are define relationship between objects so by defining it child class object also going to effect if you make any change to Parent class object.

Now you have mentioned `cascade = “all”` you are telling cascading will be apply for `insert/update/delete`

Cascading can be apply `save/update/delete` etc.

Now if `cascade = “none”` then only Parent class object will effected and not the child class.